# Postgres list partitioning

Tags: postgresql-performance

We have a  postgres table which is close to 300GB and its growing more. We have a column "name" which is unique to each and every record. We decided to go with list partition based on the first character of name. For example, apple.com will go under partition_a , godaddy.com will go under partition_g and so on. So we created partitions a to z and also 0 to 9. We gave  " partition by list ("left((name)::text,1)) " in the main table and created partitions for a to z and 0 to 9. Problem is after inserting data, when we run select query for apple.com, instead of checking partition_a , optimizer checking in all partitions. I clearly see in explain plan, its scanning all partitions. Partition pruning is not happening.  Partition pruning parameter is already enabled . Please help us to fix the issue. I am thinking we can't use function for partition definition and that is making to scan all partitions. Is it correct?  If not, why its scanning all partitions?

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)